# Returning NA values to column when using left_join

Tags: r, dplyr, data-wrangling

I'm attempting to join two data sets by a column, but the added column from the second data set returns N/A values.

My first data set looks like this, with dimensions 80x7:

```
# A tibble: 6 × 7
  country     year migrants       pop   rgdpe gdpcap  migpop
  <chr>      <int>    <int>     <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>
1 Algeria     1960   858054 11326767.  67245.  5937. 0.0758 
2 Argentina   1960   156239 20545674.  66827.  3253. 0.00760
3 Australia   1960   164696 10470019. 161636. 15438. 0.0157 
4 Austria     1960   659044  7093828.  71716. 10110. 0.0929 
5 Bangladesh  1960    53136 52080069.  83272.  1599. 0.00102
6 Belgium     1960   982848  9113383. 102919. 11293. 0.108
```

and my second data set looks like this, with dimension 248x2:

```
# A tibble: 6 × 2
  country         subregion         
  <chr>           <chr>             
1  Afghanistan    Southern Asia     
2  Albania        Southern Europe   
3  Algeria        Northern Africa   
4  American Samoa Polynesia         
5  Andorra        Southern Europe   
6  Angola         Sub-Saharan Africa
```

I attempt to join them by the column 'country', like so:

```
newdataset <- Tomig_sixty %>% left_join(subregion, by = "country")
```

However, the result turn out as below:

```
# A tibble: 6 × 8
  country     year migrants       pop   rgdpe gdpcap  migpop subregion
  <chr>      <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>    
1 Algeria     1960   858054 11326767.  67245.  5937. 0.0758  NA       
2 Argentina   1960   156239 20545674.  66827.  3253. 0.00760 NA       
3 Australia   1960   164696 10470019. 161636. 15438. 0.0157  NA       
4 Austria     1960   659044  7093828.  71716. 10110. 0.0929  NA       
5 Bangladesh  1960    53136 52080069.  83272.  1599. 0.00102 NA       
6 Belgium     1960   982848  9113383. 102919. 11293. 0.108   NA
```

Returning NA in the new column 'subregion'. I would have expected values like 'Nothern Africa' to be joined to Algeria, but I can't figure out where the error is.

The output of dput is:

```
> dput(head(Tomig_sixty))
structure(list(country = c("Algeria", "Argentina", "Australia", 
"Austria", "Bangladesh", "Belgium"), year = c(1960L, 1960L, 1960L, 
1960L, 1960L, 1960L), migrants = c(858054L, 156239L, 164696L, 
659044L, 53136L, 982848L), pop = c(11326767.4450945, 20545673.5721746, 
10470018.916696, 7093827.95538466, 52080069.3872048, 9113382.52048344
), rgdpe = c(67244.7109375, 66827.484375, 161635.515625, 71715.84375, 
83272.4765625, 102919.1796875), gdpcap = c(5936.79628927342, 
3252.63049372622, 15437.9392158736, 10109.6113693543, 1598.93175148032, 
11293.1921222638), migpop = c(0.0757545349244028, 0.00760447202916713, 
0.015730248561191, 0.092903860108384, 0.00102027513836329, 0.107846674688671
)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), na.action = structure(c(`1` = 1L, `2` = 2L, `4` = 4L, `5` = 5L, 
`6` = 6L, `7` = 7L, `8` = 8L, `10` = 10L, `11` = 11L, `14` = 14L, 
`15` = 15L, `16` = 16L, `18` = 18L, `19` = 19L, `21` = 21L, `23` = 23L, 
`24` = 24L, `25` = 25L, `26` = 26L, `27` = 27L, `29` = 29L, `30` = 30L, 
`33` = 33L, `36` = 36L, `37` = 37L, `43` = 43L, `44` = 44L, `45` = 45L, 
`46` = 46L, `48` = 48L, `49` = 49L, `50` = 50L, `51` = 51L, `52` = 52L, 
`54` = 54L, `55` = 55L, `58` = 58L, `60` = 60L, `61` = 61L, `62` = 62L, 
`64` = 64L, `65` = 65L, `66` = 66L, `69` = 69L, `70` = 70L, `71` = 71L, 
`72` = 72L, `73` = 73L, `76` = 76L, `78` = 78L, `79` = 79L, `80` = 80L, 
`81` = 81L, `84` = 84L, `85` = 85L, `88` = 88L, `89` = 89L, `90` = 90L, 
`93` = 93L, `94` = 94L, `100` = 100L, `101` = 101L, `103` = 103L, 
`104` = 104L, `105` = 105L, `106` = 106L, `107` = 107L, `108` = 108L, 
`109` = 109L, `110` = 110L, `111` = 111L, `112` = 112L, `113` = 113L, 
`114` = 114L, `115` = 115L, `116` = 116L, `117` = 117L, `118` = 118L, 
`122` = 122L, `124` = 124L, `125` = 125L, `126` = 126L, `127` = 127L, 
`128` = 128L, `129` = 129L, `131` = 131L, `132` = 132L, `133` = 133L, 
`134` = 134L, `135` = 135L, `138` = 138L, `139` = 139L, `140` = 140L, 
`143` = 143L, `144` = 144L, `149` = 149L, `150` = 150L, `151` = 151L, 
`153` = 153L, `155` = 155L, `157` = 157L, `161` = 161L, `163` = 163L, 
`164` = 164L, `165` = 165L, `167` = 167L, `169` = 169L, `170` = 170L, 
`171` = 171L, `172` = 172L, `173` = 173L, `174` = 174L, `176` = 176L, 
`177` = 177L, `178` = 178L, `180` = 180L, `181` = 181L, `182` = 182L, 
`183` = 183L, `187` = 187L, `188` = 188L, `189` = 189L, `190` = 190L, 
`191` = 191L, `192` = 192L, `196` = 196L, `197` = 197L, `198` = 198L, 
`200` = 200L, `202` = 202L, `203` = 203L, `204` = 204L, `207` = 207L, 
`208` = 208L, `209` = 209L, `211` = 211L, `212` = 212L, `216` = 216L, 
`217` = 217L, `218` = 218L, `219` = 219L, `220` = 220L, `221` = 221L, 
`222` = 222L, `223` = 223L, `224` = 224L), class = "omit"))
```

```
> dput(head(subregion))
structure(list(country = c(" Afghanistan", " Albania", " Algeria", 
" American Samoa", " Andorra", " Angola"), subregion = c("Southern Asia", 
"Southern Europe", "Northern Africa", "Polynesia", "Southern Europe", 
"Sub-Saharan Africa")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Hi Jhau16! Please, add the result of `dput(head(Tomig_sixty))` and `dput(head(subregion))` to your question. It will be easier to help you :-)

Comment: There's probably some invisible character. Try to apply the function `trimws` to each `country` column before `join` . `mutate(country = trimws(country)`

Comment: Yes, there is a blank before each string. Use trimws and it will work fine

Comment: You can see in your `dput` that in the `subregion` data frame all the countries start with a space: `" Algeria"` instead of `"Algeria"`.  You need to remove those spaces so there is an exact match. Edo's suggestion to use `trimws` will work.

Comment: `subregion <- subregion %>% mutate(country = trimws(country))`. Then your `join` code.

Comment: Trimws didn't work but apparently it was a character with ASCII code 160 called a "non-breaking space." Using the str_trim() from the stringr package did the trick. Thanks for leading me on the right way!

Answer (score 0):

As I wrote in the comment, you just need to trim the leading blanks.

In this solution you will still see some NAs because I only used your samples.

```r
library(dplyr)

subregion <- subregion %>% mutate(country = trimws(country))
newdataset <- Tomig_sixty %>% left_join(subregion, by = "country")
newdataset
#> # A tibble: 6 x 8
#>   country     year migrants       pop   rgdpe gdpcap  migpop subregion      
#>   <chr>      <int>    <int>     <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>          
#> 1 Algeria     1960   858054 11326767.  67245.  5937. 0.0758  Northern Africa
#> 2 Argentina   1960   156239 20545674.  66827.  3253. 0.00760 <NA>           
#> 3 Australia   1960   164696 10470019. 161636. 15438. 0.0157  <NA>           
#> 4 Austria     1960   659044  7093828.  71716. 10110. 0.0929  <NA>           
#> 5 Bangladesh  1960    53136 52080069.  83272.  1599. 0.00102 <NA>           
#> 6 Belgium     1960   982848  9113383. 102919. 11293. 0.108   <NA>
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

The real question here is how those blanks were generated in the first place. There may be a hidden data quality issue. Have a look into it.